# How should I add spent coffee grounds to Azaleas?

Tags: fertilizer, coffee-grounds, azaleas

My garden has rocks and weed fabric.

Must I remove both and add the grounds to the soil or can I just add on them on top of the rocks?

Answer (score 2):

They must be added directly on top of the soil - just throwing them onto rocks won't have any impact other than to make a nasty looking mess. Given the minor effect they have on soil acidification, in your situation, I'd find it far too inconvenient to dispose of them in this manner.

Comment: Can you mix them with water to form a "juice" and then pour it on top of soil?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to add coffee grounds to compost and then add to the soil? I thought nitrogen from grounded coffee can be utilized only if decomposed. I was referring to the following question. http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/801/how-do-i-apply-spent-coffee-grounds-as-a-fertilizer?rq=1

Comment: @ViSu - yep, that's certainly an option if you want to utilise any remaining nutrients in the grounds. However, as azaleas were specifically mentioned in the question, it's more likely the questioner was looking to utilize their acidifying effect rather than any slight nutritional value, although that's an assumption on my part given the info available.

Comment: @Danger14 - you mean making a sort of coffee grounds tea. You can if you want, but I doubt it'll be of much value to your azaleas. And you've still got the grounds to dispose of - put 'em on the compost heap if you've got one.